# Reset orders / invoices - 1.9.2.4 - Database error

Tags: database

I´ve a big problem with the reset of my test orders / invoices.

I run this mySQL command in phpMyAdmin on my database:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_invoice_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_address`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_payment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_order_status_history`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_address_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_item_option`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_payment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_comment`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_grid`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_item`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_flat_shipment_track`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_payment_transaction`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_aggregated_created`; 
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order_tax_item`;
TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`; 
TRUNCATE `tag`; 
TRUNCATE `tag_relation`; 
TRUNCATE `tag_summary`; 
TRUNCATE `wishlist`; 
TRUNCATE `log_quote`; 
TRUNCATE `report_event`; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_creditmemo_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_invoice_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order_status_history` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_address_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_item_option` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_payment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_comment` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_grid` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_shipment_track` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_invoiced_aggregated_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_payment_transaction` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_aggregated_created` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sales_order_tax_item` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag_relation` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `tag_summary` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `log_quote` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

But i always get this error: 
 #1146 - Table 'db63844xxxx.sales_flat_creditmemo' doesn't exist

I don´t know what i should do. I worked on it the whole day, but i doesn´t work. Please help me.

Comment: I presume you don't have table prefixes?

Comment: I think i´ve a prefix. Please look on the screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvsb00whnsg4u0m/mysql.jpg?dl=0 maybe you can see there a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The link is saying you have deleted the image but if your tables have a prefix then simply add the prefix to the queries